# Twitter Bootstrap Horizontal form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form using Bootstrap where the fields are horizontal but the labels are above the field. The HTML i have is

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>

        <label>Firstname</label><input class="span12" type="text">
        <label>Surname</label><input class="span12" type="text">

        <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label><input id="PhoneNumber" class="span6" type="text">
        <label for="MobilePhone">Mobile Phone</label><input id="MobilePhone" class="span6" type="text">

        <label>Email Address</label><input class="span12" type="text">

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>Address Details</legend>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This produces a form that looks like

[image: No good form]

But what I want is something that looks like

[image: Good form]

What Twitter Bootstrap magic do I need for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like I managed to solve my own problem. Html changed to

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>

        <label>Firstname</label><input class="span12" type="text">

        <label>Surname</label><input class="span12" type="text">

        <div class="controls-row">
            <div class="control-group span6">
                <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="PhoneNumber" class="span12" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span6">
                <label for="MobilePhone">Mobile Phone</label>
                <input id="MobilePhone" class="span12" type="text">
            </div>                          
        </div>

        <label>Email Address</label><input class="span12" type="text">

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="span6">
        <legend>Address Details</legend>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```